# Python hash appropriate to be a file name

Tags: python, windows, hash, filenames

I have to store some temporary files (it does not have to be human-readable). Since I'm creating them from different threads, I don't want to do difficult communication between threads - which name is reserved or already used etc.

The best option seems to be using `hash`.

Example:

I have many records under the block 'Žilina', '54845'. I want to store them temporary into some txt file.

So I would do this:

```
write_into_temp_file(name_of_the_file=hashlib.file_name_hash('Žilina54845'))
```

And I can be sure (99.9999 %) that there won't be any collision with another temporary file.

I've tried to find some inspiration in this question [Short Python alphanumeric hash with minimal collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510716/short-python-alphanumeric-hash-with-minimal-collisions) but those `hashes` contains signs which are not allowed to be a part of the file name. For example `==`

**EDIT:**

My OS is `Windows`

Comment: Why not use [uuid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python)?

Comment: I has to depend on unique string. In fact, there can be more files created in one thread etc.

Comment: I don't understand, what's stopping you from generating uuids for each file?

Answer (score 2):

Normally hash is not containing any special character...

```
from hashlib import sha512
import base64

my_file_name="myfilenameverylongtohide.myextension"
hash_filename= sha512(my_file_name).hexdigest()

print hash_filename

>>> e4cd8ae2b7a1c0eb44a987f5b89e43b892709a4b9a072b0fa579715da5becf40318cbc972131485f2132209a76a0ffc199973072665c639d628f641c8b872c8
```

If you definitely prefer to use base64 notation you may replace the "=" (last character) by "

```
b64_hash_filename= base64.b64encode(hash_filename).replace('=','')
print b64_hash_filename

>>> YWU0Y2Q4YWUyYjdhMWMwZWI0NGE5ODdmNWI4OWU0M2I4OTI3MDlhNGI5YTA3MmIwZmE1Nzk3MTVkYTViZWNmNDAzMThjYmM5NzIxMzE0ODVmMjEzMjIwOWE3NmEwZmZjMTk5OTczMDcyNjY1YzYzOWQ2MjhmNjQxYzhiODcyYzg
```