# Creating a unique value per row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Acquire raw data --> transform it and join it with other files --> email to end-users for review

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `'employee_id'+'customer_id'+'timestamp'` is long, and you are interested in something that is *unlikely* to have collisions, you can replace it with a hash. The range and quality of the hash will determine the probability of collisions. Perhaps the simplest is to use the [builtin `hash`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash).  Assuming your DataFrame is `df`, and the columns are strings, this is

```
(df.employee_id + df.customer_id + df.timestamp).apply(hash)
```

If you want greater control of the size and collision probability, see [this piece on non-crypotgraphic hash functions in Python](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-hashing-function-in-python).

---

**Edit**

Building on [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510716/short-python-alphanumeric-hash-with-minimal-collisions), you could build 10-character hashes like this:

```
import hashlib
df['survey_id'] = (df.employee_id + df.customer_id + df.timestamp).apply(
    lambda s: hashlib.md5(s).digest().encode('base64')[: 10])
```

Comment: That was pretty simple. Is there a way to .apply some of the hashlib options if I wanted to try that library?

Comment: @LanceDacey Sure, you could do it in many ways, including a lambda function. If you have some example question in mind, drop a comment here.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to encryption but I know I have seen some hashing which uses A-Z, a-z, 0-9 for example. My goal would be to combine those three columns into a new temporary column, and then hash it into a survey_id column. If we can make the id column a shorter string then that would be better (the combined column is pretty long, like mine would be ldacey201603081114239999999999).

So df['survey_id'] = some hashlib function on df['combined']

Comment: @LanceDacey 1. I think that *non-cryptographic* hash functions are what you're looking for here. Cryptographic hash functions are extremely slow functions that attempt to make reverse engineering difficult - which is irrelevant to you. 2. Updated the answer - see if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight and the example! I successfully implemented a solution now which seems to be working.

Comment: One quick question too - these hash values are random right? Is there a similar method to create a hash which is just a different format of a long string? For example, what if I have two files and wanted to add an ID to represent those three columns and I wanted it to be the same on both files (which are read into memory at different times)? Would hash allow that? In pandas I do all of my joins based on 3 column merges, it would be pretty nice to just create a row ID which would be the same on all of the files with that same combination (timestamp, customer_id, employee_id)

Comment: @LanceDacey I'd be happy to address your question, but it's a bit hard to do so in the comments section - I just don't understand what you're asking, exactly, and you can't format or show examples in the comments. Perhaps you could open a new question? If you drop a note here, I'll be happy to have a look at it (as I'm sure will others too).

Comment: Cool thanks, I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990352/creating-unique-integer-ids-which-are-equal-on-different-files

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a modularized function, save this into a file for use where needed. (for Pandas DataFrames)

`df` is your dataframe, `columns` is a list of columns to hash over, and `name` is the name of your new column with hash values.

Returns a **copy** of the original dataframe with a new column containing the hash of each row.

```
def hash_cols(df, columns, name="hash"):
    new_df = df.copy()
    def func(row, cols):
        col_data = []
        for col in cols:
            col_data.append(str(row.at[col]))

        col_combined = ''.join(col_data).encode()
        hashed_col = sha256(col_combined).hexdigest()
        return hashed_col

    new_df[name] = new_df.apply(lambda row: func(row,columns), axis=1)

    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, that I solved thusly:

```
import hashlib
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'mine': ['yours', 'amazing', 'pajamas'], 'have': ['something', 'nothing', 'between'], 'num': [1, 2, 3]})
hashes = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    hashes.append(hashlib.md5(str(row).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
# if you want the hashes in the df, 
# in my case, I needed them to form a JSON entry per row
df['hash'] = hashes
```

The results will form an md5 hash, but you can really use any hash function you need to.